# Does Python's multiprocessing package's spawning use the file state when the parent process started or the file state at the time of process spawning?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

If I have some Python code with a long setup stage, which eventually spawns processes, will the spawned process be based on the Python files at the start of the parent process or the files at the time of spawning?

That is, I start the parent Python process. Then I go and edit the Python files and finish editing them before the parent process spawns other processes. Finally, the parent process spawns child processes which use code from those files. Will the child processes use the code as it was when the parent started? Or the code as it was at the time of the process spawning?

Comment: This depends on your platform - more specifically, the choice between 'fork' and 'spawn' modes that `multiprocessing` makes based on your platform.

Comment: @jasonharper, do you mean that fork will base use the files as collected by the parent process, while spawn will use the files at the time of process spawning? Or something else?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods seems to suggest that even in spawn version, necessary "file descriptors and handles" will be used from the parent. So this may include the Python loaded into memory as the parent sees them?

Comment: No, that's not how Python handles source code, and it's not how files work.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, sorry, it's not entirely clear to me which statement you're saying is not how it works. That the spawn version of multiprocess does not use any file descriptors from the parent? Or that though it does use those file descriptors, that doesn't mean it doesn't re-load the updated files? Or is this comment referring to a statement original post? If so, which one?

Comment: Python doesn't keep source files in memory, and even if it did, the in-memory copy would be a completely different thing from a file descriptor or file handle. Python keeps compiled bytecode in memory, for code objects that haven't been reclaimed. (Most function code objects won't be reclaimed until program shutdown, but I believe most class and module code objects get reclaimed at the end of class or module body execution.)

Comment: I would rather suggest you use celery which uses multiprocessing under the hood! though named as billiard! this will reduce a lot of your pain as celery is a high-level framework for managing long-running background processes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the operating system.

In Linux `multiprocessing` uses `fork` system call to create child processes. As a result, the child process "inherits" the bytecode of all python sources and does not re-read the sources. That is, in Linux the child will not recognize the changes.

In Windows `multiprocessing` creates child processes [using `_winapi.CreateProcess`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/34a49aa3e4d023b5f9e9029f4f1ec68f1a8a8120/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_win32.py#L73). The child initialises itself from scratch, that is it will read all source files again, including the modified ones.

Proof.

Here is a small example where the main processes modifies one of the source files.

somelib.py: prints out the process ID of the process that loads it.

```py
import os

print("SomeLib loaded in process", os.getpid())
```

test.py: before spawning the child process it patches `somelib.py`

```
from multiprocessing import Process
# somelib prints process ID and, if patched, an extra line
import somelib

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("The main process is patching SomeLib")
    with open("somelib.py", "a+") as patch:
        patch.write("\n\nprint('SomeLib is patched')")
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    # Spawn the the child
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The output in Linux:

```
SomeLib loaded in process 70
The main process is patching SomeLib
hello bob
```

`somelib.py` was modified, but the child ignored that because of fork.

The output in Windows

```
SomeLib loaded in process 22512
The main process is patching SomeLib
SomeLib loaded in process 17008
SomeLib is patched
hello bob
```

See? The child with pid 17008 "re-loaded" `somelib.py` and processed the modified one.

Comment: Just to clarify, it the main factor is then the [start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods), correct? The operating system sets the default start method (and limits which start methods can be used), but the operating system is not the deciding factor, but rather the start method is, right? If you're using Linux, but set the start method to `spawn` you will still get the case that is the default in Windows. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Yes. If you use `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` in Linux, you will get the same behavior with re-reading source files in child processes.